# In RSpec, how can I mock a method called with a constant argument?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I'm creating a gem that will have a constant in whatever app it is being used in (after a generator is run), but that constant doesn't exist in the gem itself.  I'm having an issue with RSpec inside the gem not skipping over the part of code that is calling the constant.  A simple example of what is going on is below.

```
class Foo
  def self.do_something
    Bar.send(FakeConstant.name)  #Bar.send is a valid class and method
  end
end
```

foo_spec.rb

```
it 'does something'
  expect(Bar).to receive(send).and_return('skipped!')
  Foo.do_something
end
```

rspec output

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FakeConstant
```

I want to write the test so that it skips over the `Bar.send` call completely so that it never knows that there is a bad constant inside of it. There really isn't a good way to get around this.

Comment: `I'm creating a gem that will have a constant in whatever app it is being used in (after a generator is run), but that constant doesn't exist in the gem itself` - this is not the best idea. What would be the use case here? It would be much better idea to provide object in the constant through a configuration.

Answer (score 3):

RSpec's `stub_const` method allows you to stub a constant:

```
it 'does something'
  stub_const(FakeConstant, double(name: "Fakey McFakerson"))
  expect(Bar).to receive(send).and_return('skipped!')
  Foo.do_something
end
```

More here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants/stub-defined-constant

That said, I agree with BroiSatse that it would be probably be nicer to provide a more dynamic means of getting that information into your code that could be manipulated in tests with less trickery.